# Windows 7: app crashing/hanging on "save as" dialog

Tags: windows-7

now this is really annoying - I'm having a global problem in Windows 7:
when using the system's "save as"-file dialog, the main app will just hang.

the mouse-cursor is showing progress, the whole app is hanging and I need to terminate it manually. it's happening with every app! (notepad, word, graphics app).
I'm assuming it's something with the system enumerating the harddisk-drivenames or something.
any idea how to fix this?

by the way - when viewing the problem details - it's telling the module - it's `msonsext.dll`,
looks like some office thing to me.

Comment: msonsext.dll seems to be related to Sharepoint.  Do you use Sharepoint or try to save files to it?  If you rename msonsext.dll to msonsext.off does the Save As Dialog stop crashing?  What about when you unplug your computer from all networks, issue go away?

Answer (score 1):

Removing / Renaming msonsext.dll fixed this for me. Now I wonder what the correct fix is.